# How to use om_exec with nxlog on Windows

Tags: nxlog

I am attempting to use nxlog to read and parse IIS logs on Windows Server 2008 r2. Because I have particular requirements for these logs, I would like to use om_exec to send the log entries to a custom tool, where I will do the required work and process them as I need to. My  block looks like this:

```
<Output streamout>
    Module      om_exec
    Command     'dump_input.exe'
</Output>
```

This configuration results in this error message:

> ERROR couldn't execute process 'dump_input.exe'; The parameter is incorrect.

I have tried fully-qualifying the command name, using well-known commands (such as cmd.exe), non-existent commands, anything, and the error is always the same.

Does om_exec work on Windows, and if so, how can I use it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a full path (else the path must be relative to Spooldir) and it must not be quoted:

```
<Output streamout>
    Module      om_exec
    Command     C:\path\to\dump_input.exe
</Output>
```